# Is there a Rust crate that implements the SQL date and interval types?

Tags: datetime, date, date-format

I went looking for a Rust crate (on lib.rs) that implements DateTime and found chrono.rs.  However, I have two issues.

1. I cannot find a function that takes a string representing an SQL date and converts that into the external representation.  I found a variety of conversion functions but they all require format strings specifying how the date is laid out in the string, but I don't know what the format specifier should be.  The parser for SQL is simply handing me this date as a string and I don't know how the string is formatted.  (The code I am parsing is one of the tpch queries, so it includes both a date and an interval, which I'm hoping can be converted to a "duration".)
2. The backend code which I am connecting to expects the date to be represented as a 64-bit unsigned integer.  Is there a specific representation that is used for such?

(Note, I asked on the Rust discord server, but only got the answer that the task should be "easy".)

Answer (score 1):

`Chrono::NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s, fmt)` mostly solved the first problem.  I don't have intervals yet, but I can do dates.  I do have to specify the format of the date, e.g. `"%Y-%m-%d"` but it seems the only option to do so.

And to get an integer, I am using the `timestamp()` function.  That gives me a signed integer, which I can then convert to unsigned.